# How do I add camera rotation in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and I'm trying to figure out how to rotate the main camera from one position (in perspective of a person). I've tried looking for scripts and writing out but it never works.

here's what the scripts would look like...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb6hU.png)

I honestly don't know what I am doing so if this is actually a simple problem to solve, please don't be too harsh. Or do.

I am using unity 2018, btw.

Comment: Please don't add code as Images .. rather copy paste the code into your question directly and format it is such using the `{ }` button of the Editor here. Also define better what `it never works` means...

Comment: In general: I just guess what you get here is a gimbal lock problem. You should rotate about **global Y** but **local X** to get the results you are after. As this is kind of the most basic request for ego perspective games there are already tons of examples in the web. E.g. https://forum.unity.com/threads/simple-first-person-camera-script.417611 (first hit for a Google search for `Unity ego perspective camera` btw)

Answer (score 0):

Get the standard assets, use and look into the FPS Controller.